# GetForegroundWindow from service on windows 7

Tags: c++, windows-7

I am using GetForegroundWindow() from a service as i want to monitor the window that is in focus but the function is returning null on windows 7 due to interactive user problem. Is there any way by which i can get the focused window in my service?

```
HWINSTA hWinStaUser = OpenWindowStation(_T("WinSta0"), FALSE, MAXIMUM_ALLOWED); 
    if (SetProcessWindowStation(hWinStaUser)) 
    {
        /* -- Open user's desktop "Default". -- */
        HDESK hDeskUser = OpenInputDesktop(0,FALSE,MAXIMUM_ALLOWED);
        //HDESK hDeskUser = OpenDesktop(_T("Default"), 0, FALSE, MAXIMUM_ALLOWED);
        /* -- Set thread desktop to "Default". -- */ 
        if (SetThreadDesktop(hDeskUser)) 
        {   
            HWND hwndActiveWin = GetForegroundWindow();

            int  idActive      = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwndActiveWin, NULL);
            if ( AttachThreadInput(GetCurrentThreadId(), idActive, TRUE) )
            {
                HWND  hwndFocused = GetFocus ();    // focused control within the active window, i.e. focus throughout the screen
                if(hwndFocused != NULL)
                {
                    DWORD dwProcessID = 0;      
                    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwndFocused, &dwProcessID);
                    processPid = dwProcessID;
                }               
                AttachThreadInput(GetCurrentThreadId(), idActive, FALSE);       
            }           
        }
```

Answer (score 6):

you need to understand the problem itself. services cannot interact with desktop because of security risk and because there can be many desktops (many logged in users). GetForegroundWindow() is an interaction with desktop. There's no simple workaround. Complicated one involves separate process running as windows application (not a service) and communicating with your service.

Comment: Thanks Alex.. So you mean if i have to achieve this on windows 7 i will have to create a process that does this and interacts with my service? Is there no way by which i can get the active desktop and the windows there?

Comment: I Want to know how do i get the window in focus on the desktop in windows 7.. i am using C++.. It would be great if you can help me with this..

Comment: The simplest way is to use `GetForegroundWindow()`. Since you cannot use it from your service, you need to implement separate user-mode application that does this and sends this info to your service using some kind of interprocess communication, e.g. by network socket

Comment: Is WM_SETFOCUS and WM_KILLFOCUS going to do the job for me? How do i implement it in service?

Comment: How can i achieve the above using interprocess communication? I gues i will have to use named pipe..if you could help me with this as i am new to win32..